# what does this symbol '()' do after closing '{}'in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I'm really sorry with the title, and im sorry if im asking this noob questions here, because i don't know what the keyword for this in google.

Ok, first i'm new to javascript and still learning this programming language. so i've seen this alot, but i don't know what it's mean

```
var myapp = function(){

  var a = 'a';
  var b = function(){
    //some code goes here
  }

  return {

    init: function(){
    b();
    //some code goes here

    }

  }

}() <-- what is it?;
```

So i've been wondering what this symbol '()' do at the end. and why many people writing a function inside a variable?

Comment: It tells the Javascript interpreter to execute the function immediately after it is defined.

Comment: The function is executed just after it's declaration. It's called a module pattern if you want to search about it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the link, sorry if i;m duplicating question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the function is being exectued right after its declaration

On the other hand, declaring the function this way:

```
var myapp = function(){
```

lets you use it as an object..

Then you can use myapp.init() for example

Comment: is this a good practice? thank you for the answer